# Missing Windows Boot Option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Hi everyone before anything else I would like to say that I'm new to this and this is my first post so I'm sorry if the fonts,formats or knowledge are not up to standard.

Anyway I've researched a bit on my problem of not being able to boot my windows. I've tried using the boot repair too as suggested by some but to no avail and here's the link they mentioned.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Qzx42PKjPp/

Please do guide me to get the information needed to solve this problem as I do not know what information is needed.

Not sure this information would help but I'm quite puzzled on this problem as before this problem occur, I was able to use windows without any problem then after I rebooted to ubuntu for some work and back to windows, this happened. All this in less than an hour.

Additional information:

- Windows was installed first but I currently couldn't check which version it was as I can only use ubuntu now
- Installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Please tell us which OS was on your PC first; Windows (and which version), or Ubuntu 18.04.4? Please click [edit] and add that information to your question.